# PowerMock trying to mock static getConnection gives illegalStateException: Failed to transform class

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock, illegalstateexception

I am trying to make static getConnection() method from a class JDBCConnectionFactory. I am using powerMock + mockito for mocking along with Junit4.

#### Solutions tried :

1. Googled for it and changed a lot of javassist.jar versions. None of them worked.
2. The below mentioned code works. But when I replace Another.class with JDBCConnectionFactory, it starts giving the below mentioned exception.
3. When I remove PrepareFortest annotation and try to run this JUNIT, it starts executing the getConnection method itself(which I want to mock).

   ```
   import org.junit.Test;
   import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
   import org.mockito.Mockito;
   import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
   import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

   @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
   @PrepareForTest(AnotherClass.class)
   public class MockitoTester {

      @Test
      public void myTest() throws Exception {

         mockStatic(AnotherClass.class);
         Mockito.when(AnotherClass.getStaticString()).thenReturn("mock static string ");
         System.out.println(AnotherClass.getStaticString());

      }

   }
   ```

I am getting the below exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to transform class with name org.onesync.dq.gui.testng.testNG.MockitoTester. Reason: 3
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:207)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:145)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:67)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:133)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:39)
    at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.createTestDelegators(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:217)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.<init>(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:59)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.<init>(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:32)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.<init>(PowerMockRunner.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:31)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:29)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:24)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.<init>(JUnit4TestReference.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestClassReference.<init>(JUnit4TestClassReference.java:25)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at javassist.bytecode.ByteArray.write16bit(ByteArray.java:40)
    at javassist.bytecode.StackMapTable$Shifter.update(StackMapTable.java:744)
    at javassist.bytecode.StackMapTable$Shifter.sameFrame(StackMapTable.java:720)
    at javassist.bytecode.StackMapTable$Walker.stackMapFrames(StackMapTable.java:194)
    at javassist.bytecode.StackMapTable$Walker.parse(StackMapTable.java:179)
    at javassist.bytecode.StackMapTable$Shifter.doit(StackMapTable.java:714)
    at javassist.bytecode.StackMapTable.shiftPc(StackMapTable.java:693)
    at javassist.bytecode.CodeIterator.insertGap0(CodeIterator.java:676)
    at javassist.bytecode.CodeIterator.insertGap(CodeIterator.java:636)
    at javassist.bytecode.CodeIterator.insertGapCore(CodeIterator.java:467)
    at javassist.bytecode.CodeIterator.insertGap(CodeIterator.java:413)
    at javassist.expr.Expr.replace0(Expr.java:298)
    at javassist.expr.FieldAccess.replace(FieldAccess.java:213)
    at org.powermock.core.transformers.impl.MainMockTransformer$PowerMockExpressionEditor.edit(MainMockTransformer.java:276)
    at javassist.expr.ExprEditor.loopBody(ExprEditor.java:197)
    at javassist.expr.ExprEditor.doit(ExprEditor.java:90)
    at javassist.CtClassType.instrument(CtClassType.java:1289)
    at org.powermock.core.transformers.impl.MainMockTransformer.transform(MainMockTransformer.java:75)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:203)
    ... 29 more
```

Hope the above information helps. Any ideas/approaches/suggestions are
welcome.  Thanks

Comment: Exactly what versions of junit, mockito, powermock and javassist are you using?  Solution number 3 is definitely NOT the answer, you need the `@PrepareForTest` annotation.

Comment: What JDK are you using?

Comment: Junit 4 , mockito-all - 1.9.5 , powermock - 1.5 , javassist- tried versions 3.10 to 3.17, JAVA 1.6

Comment: This test worked for me almost immediately.  Could you post your 'AnotherClass' or something more concrete so I can get a better idea what the problem may be?

Comment: I'm not sure but ususaly I sepcify PowerMockito to be statically imported. Sorry don't see that in your imports as well in the code

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you need to use the doReturn() syntax. Have you tried the following with JDBCConnectionFactory? I'll use your AnotherClass example:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(AnotherClass.class)
public class MockitoTester {

  @Test
  public void myTest() throws Exception {
    mockStatic(AnotherClass.class);
    PowerMockito.doReturn("mock static string ").when(AnotherClass.class, "getStaticString");
    System.out.println(AnotherClass.getStaticString());
  }
}
```

See also PowerMockitoStubber at https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.powermock/powermock-api-mockito/1.5

Comment: Thank you so much, it really helps me!
I dont know wh Powermock gives two "same" method like that, so confuss :(

Answer (score 0):

please look [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when running PowerMock test](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/powermock/LSJ2g-7ws_k), I solved by this way, update javassist.jar version